# Cluster identifier in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb

I would like to implement a licensing solution in my software which restricts/binds usage to one MongoDB cluster (the cluster size and composition does not matter - can be standalone as well). Is there any identifier provided by MongoDB which I could use for this purpose?

Comment: Do you want you software to have a maximum of one connection to a MongoDB cluster, or your mongoDB cluster to have max 1 open connection?

Comment: @CasperDijkstra I want to bind any number of instances of my program to only connect to one cluster. I want to prevent multiple "co-location" activations this way.

Comment: I see. I'm not sure if there's any identifier provided by MongoDB, but maybe it can be solved from within your software. Which programming language did you use for your software ?

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for *access control* settings on the cluster level. You can create **sharded cluster users**:

```
db.getSiblingDB.("clustername").createUser(
  {
    "user": "<name>",
    "pwd": "<password>",
    "roles": [ { "role" : "readWrite", "db" : "clustername" } ]
  }
)
```

and a detailed description can be found https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/enforce-keyfile-access-control-in-existing-sharded-cluster-no-downtime/ under **Configure Sharded Cluster Admin User and Client Users**.
If you ensure that each user of your application gets an `username` and `password` in mongodb (your software needs to take care of that), you can guarantee that they can *only access this cluster*.

Comment: This would be a good solution if the DB itself would run online, but unfortunately it's on-premise as well as the software, my intention is to prevent the customer from buying a license for 100 users, starting 2 separate MongoDB clusters, and voila, they have 2x100 users using the software.